# Create an angular form that would follow a decision tree

Tags: angular, decision-tree, angular-forms

I would like to build an Angular app that would ask questions to a user and generate the next question according to their answer (following a decision tree).

For example (I'll expose multiple scenarios, each one on one line, questions in italic and answers in bold):

```
                  CHEST PAIN ? 
                yes/          \no
                              RATE?
                         <60 /    \ >100
                                 HYPO ?
                              no/    \ yes
                                     **SEDATE**(result of the decision tree)
```

Could you please give me some clues on how to achieve that? This looks like a tree (or a graph). Should I store my questions in such a data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctxwhh) work for you?

```js
public readonly countries = ["France", "Germany"];
public readonly cities = {
    "France": ["Paris", "Lyon", "Marseille"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Hamburg"]
};

public selection = {
    country: '',
    city: ''
};
```

```html
Pick country
<select [(ngModel)]="selection.country">
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/>

<ng-container *ngIf="selection.country.length > 0">
    Pick city
    <select [(ngModel)]="selection.city">
      <option *ngFor="let c of cities[selection.country]" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
</ng-container>
```

Starts from an initial top level selection and then shows the next question depending on the previous answer.

**UPDATE 1:** I've adapted the answer based on the diagram you posted. The new solution does not use hard coded paths, instead defines a "decision tree" structure and uses that. I'll explain in more detail later, but the essence is that you only need to modify the contents of one variable and the app will still work. [New stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwsvno).

The idea is storing each node in your tree as an object like this:

```js
export class TreeNode {
  public readonly id: nodeId;
  public readonly description: string;
  public decision: boolean | null;
  public readonly yesId: nodeId | null;
  public readonly noId: nodeId | null;
  constructor(
    id: nodeId,
    description: string,
    yesId: nodeId | null,
    noId: nodeId | null
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.decision = null; // <-- must be null on creation. wait for decision from user.
    this.yesId = yesId;
    this.noId = noId;
  }
}
```

- `id` is a string, should be unique among all nodes. More on that later.
- `description` is the question/answer body.
- `decision` is the result of the Yes/No question.
- `yesId` is the `id` of the node we should navigate to, when the decision is yes.
- `noId` is the `id` of the node we should navigate to, when the decision is no.
  If a node is a leaf, then `yesId` and `noId` should both be null.

I kept all possible nodes from your drawing as a "dictionary" called `nodeList`, so we can access a node using `nodeList[id]` syntax. It looks like this now:

```js
/**
 * Possible values for a node id. This is optional, but highly encouraged.
 */
export type nodeId =
  | "chestPain"
  | "twaveInversion"
  | "rateOver100"
  | "hypotensive"
  | "nstemi"
  | "unstableAngina"
  | "sedate"
  | "qrsOver012"
  | "vtGetExpertHelp"
  | "qrsRegular"
  | "svtVagal"
  | "pwavesPresent"
  | "atrialFibrilation"
  | "aflutter"
  | "rate100temp";

/**
 * Dictionary of nodes using their id as a key.
 */
export const nodeList = {
  chestPain: new TreeNode(
    "chestPain",
    "Chest Pain?",
    "twaveInversion",
    "rateOver100"
  ),
  twaveInversion: new TreeNode(
    "twaveInversion",
    "Twave Inversion?",
    "nstemi",
    "unstableAngina"
  ),
  unstableAngina: new TreeNode("unstableAngina", "Unstable Angina", null, null),
  nstemi: new TreeNode("nstemi", "NSTEMI", null, null),
  rateOver100: new TreeNode(
    "rateOver100",
    "Rate > 100?",
    "hypotensive",
    "rate100temp"
  ),
  hypotensive: new TreeNode(
    "hypotensive",
    "Hypotensive?",
    "sedate",
    "qrsOver012"
  ),
  sedate: new TreeNode("sedate", "Sedate.", null, null),
  qrsOver012: new TreeNode(
    "qrsOver012",
    "QRS > 0.12s ?",
    "vtGetExpertHelp",
    "qrsRegular"
  ),
  vtGetExpertHelp: new TreeNode(
    "vtGetExpertHelp",
    "VT Get expert help.",
    null,
    null
  ),
  qrsRegular: new TreeNode(
    "qrsRegular",
    "QRS regular?",
    "svtVagal",
    "pwavesPresent"
  ),
  svtVagal: new TreeNode("svtVagal", "SVT Vagal", null, null),
  pwavesPresent: new TreeNode(
    "pwavesPresent",
    "Pwaves present?",
    "aflutter",
    "atrialFibrilation"
  ),
  aflutter: new TreeNode("aflutter", "Aflutter", null, null),
  atrialFibrilation: new TreeNode(
    "atrialFibrilation",
    "Afrial fibrilation",
    null,
    null
  ),
  rate100temp: new TreeNode(
    "rate100temp",
    "Rate < 100 answer (no node given)",
    null,
    null
  )
};
```

And finally, the `DecisionTreeFormComponent`:

```js
export class DecisionTreeFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public decisionTree: IDecisionTree;
  public currentNode: TreeNode;

  public treeJSONhidden: boolean = true;
  public nodeJSONhidden: boolean = true;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reset();    
  }

  public reset() {
    // Init base node and tree here.
    this.decisionTree = [];
    this.currentNode = Object.assign({}, nodeList.chestPain);
  }

  public yes() {
    this.currentNode.decision = true;
    this.pushNode();
    this.currentNode = Object.assign({}, nodeList[this.currentNode.yesId]);
    if( this.isFinal(this.currentNode)) {
      this.pushNode();
    }
  }

  public no() {
    this.currentNode.decision = false;
    this.pushNode();
    this.currentNode = Object.assign({}, nodeList[this.currentNode.noId]);
    if( this.isFinal(this.currentNode)) {
      this.pushNode();
    }
  }

  public isFinal = (node: TreeNode) => node.yesId == null && node.noId == null;

  private pushNode():void {
    this.decisionTree.push({
      node: this.currentNode,
      index: this.decisionTree.length
    });
  }
}
```

In the `reset()` method I simply initialize the `currentNode` to the chest pain question and the rest is handled by the user's selections. I keep the path as an array to display the final result when a leaf node is reached. Check out the sample HTML I've prepared in the stackblitz, but the presentation is irrelevant in this case. You can tweak it to suit your needs.

I think this is an OK solution, where you only need to change the `nodeList` and the form will work based on the values it finds there.

**Limitations:** This currently only works for YES/NO type questions. If you expect multiple selections, you can try to "refactor" the questions to be multiple true/false questions. Otherwise, we can discuss that further.

Comment: Hello, it works well. My decision tree is quite big. I edited my problem description and was wondering if I should store all the questions in a tree data structure. Do you think it would help ?

Comment: Could you provide a bigger decision tree? With at least a couple of paths completed, right now there's only 1.

Comment: Hi, here is the work I have at the moment (it is not done yet but it will give you a better idea). https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zt7WI_W_4GKzLdWyUQ3UdXTW1nwEvf8/view?usp=sharing  

The Diamond is a yes/no answer. The halved rectangle (Rate) should be a dropdown list with 3 items. I only draw the path for one, and the normal rectangles represent the outcome. Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: How big is this going to be eventually? Even an approximation/guess would be fine. The question I'm asking at the moment is if you're going to hard code all the paths or if you're going to need a more general solution. A tree of that size is OK to hard code.

Comment: It shouldn't be much bigger than that. Maybe one or two more levels. The solution I had in mind was indeed to hard code everything (As I don't know how else to do.)

Comment: Thank you for that. Awesome work. Some questions would indeed need multiple answers (the rate for example is supposed to have 3 possible options) but for now I’ll work with your solution and in a first version make the questions with multiple answers yes/no questions(instead of having one question and three answer we would have three questions and three yes/no). I’ll later try to refactor as you said (and try to think by myself).

Comment: @Remaori Just a note: your question with 3 options can be split into multiple yes/no questions. For example, you ask "Rate > 100" then no is empty. You can then ask "Rate > 60" (or whatever) and since you're on that path, it's implied that heart rate is <= 100 (since the user selected no at "Rate > 100". Also, if this answer helps you, please mark it as accepted.